# Export symbols in same namespace from a multiple files in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, module, namespaces, export

I have a typescript module, and want to define symbols in namespace 'aaa' from multiple files.

a.ts:

```
export namespace aaa {
  export const a = "a";
}
```

b.ts:

```
export namespace aaa {
  export const b = "b";
}
```

index.ts:

```
export * from "./a";
export * from "./b";
```

In the second line of index.ts, I get the following warning:

```
TS2308: Module "./b" has already exported a member named 'aaa'. Consider 
explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.
```

How does one define symbols in the same namespace across multiple files, and them export them all under index.ts ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the modules and their unique `aaa` namespaces with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

`index.ts`

```js
import * as A from "./a";
import * as B from "./b";
export default { ...A.aaa, ...B.aaa };

// or if you prefer a named export
export const aaa = { ...A.aaa, ...B.aaa };
```

`someotherfile.ts`

```js
import aaa from "aaa"

const A = aaa.A
```

However note the spread syntax is a shallow merge, so any conflicting declarations between `a.ts` and `b.ts` will instead opt to take `b.ts`'s declaration.

`a.ts`

```js
export namespace aaa {
  export const foo = "foo";
}
```

`b.ts`

```
export namespace aaa {
  export const foo = "bar";
}
```

->
`someotherfile.ts`

```js
import aaa from "aaa"

const A = aaa.foo

console.log(A) // -> 'bar'
```